# Prevent scrollbars on tooltip if no overflow?

Tags: html, css

I created a tooltip, and I have the following CSS. Please note that on Mac, works like a charm but on windows - no luck. Even when the content is not overflowing, the scrollbar tracks show. how can I have my tooltips without them? And if they need them, how can I show only the vertical one.

```
.tooltip-container {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  overflow: scroll;
  max-height: 200px;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide the x-axis with overflow-x: hidden, on the y-axis use the 'auto' value which will only show the scrollbar if needed

```
.tooltip-container {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 200px;
```

Comment: Thanks - I'll give this a try in the morning. If good, I'll be happy to accept! - thanks!